# Accessing Content Page id with dynamic generated id

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net content page as below and I currently access the controls using FindControl. Is there a way i can access these controls using ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_id. Aka using the id which is dynamically generated on the webpage rather than using find control. My concern being is that id will be constant or it keeps changing for each user/ based on server or any other param etc.,

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server"> 
    </asp:Content> 
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="id" OnClick="id_Click" Text="text"/>
    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

To access a control on server side you can use `ID` if the control is server control, in other words if it has part `runat="server"`. Suppose that `ID` of the `Button` in your example is `MyButton`, this would be the way to access it in *code behind* and, for instance, set `Enabled` property:

```
       MyButton.Enabled = true;
```